# Is it possible to alter multiple columns in one statement in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to add default values to a group of columns, but I get a syntax error when I combine them all into one statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE drawinglist 
ADD CONSTRAINT ISOKEYPLAN_DWGTITLEPREFIX_def DEFAULT 0 FOR ISOKEYPLAN_DWGTITLEPREFIX,
ADD CONSTRAINT PIPE_VENDOR_def DEFAULT 0 FOR PIPE_VENDOR;
```

Is the above syntax (or something similar) possible or do I have to separate them all out into their own statements?

Comment: Try it without the comma in between "ADD CONSTRAINT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) for `ALTER TABLE` says you can. The SQL below should work:

```
ALTER TABLE drawinglist 
ADD 
    CONSTRAINT ISOKEYPLAN_DWGTITLEPREFIX_def DEFAULT 0 FOR ISOKEYPLAN_DWGTITLEPREFIX,
    CONSTRAINT PIPE_VENDOR_def DEFAULT 0 FOR PIPE_VENDOR;
GO
```

I tested on a dev database I have and that syntax worked in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I had duplicated the ADD. Removing that and it worked. Thanks.